# Getting Stream wise Highest Marks in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables

Table1. StudentMaster

```
      ROLL      CLASS NAME         TOTALMARKS   STREAMID
---------- ---------- ------------ ---------- ----------
 12345          5 Rohit                75        100
 12346          7 Suman                95        101
 12347          5 Rajib                41        100
 12348         10 Rakesh               52        102
 12349         10 Himesh                         101
 12350          7 Mizanur              85        103
 42145          5 Mohit                          103
```

Table2. Stream

```
  STREAMID NAME         DURATION       FEES
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
   100 electrical          3       4500
   102 civil               4       5400
   103 mechanical          3       4500
   101 ece                 2       2500
```

Now I need to get the details of the student who gets the highest marks in each stream.

The output table should look like:

```
Roll     Name       Stream         HighestMarks
----     -------    ------         ------------
12345    Rohit      electrical        75
12346    Suman      ece               95
12348    Rakesh     civil             52
12350    Mizanur    mechanical        85
```

Can you please help me with the correct Oracle SQL query to retrieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? (The answer will perhaps be product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh oracle. Sql* Plus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved this problem with the simplest way possible (I think)

```
select
studentmaster.name,studentmaster.totalmarks highest_marks,stream.name stream
from studentmaster,stream
where studentmaster.streamid=stream.streamid
and totalmarks in(select max(totalmarks) from studentmaster group by streamid);
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you need a subselect with order by for select the highest marks

```
select a.ROLL as Roll, a.NAME as Name, b.NAME as Stream, a.TOTALMARKS  HighestMarks
from StudentMaster as a 
inner join Stream as b on b.STREAMID = a.STREAMID 
where a.rool in 
       (select rool from from StudentMaster 
           where (a.rool, STREAMID) in
             (select max(ROLL), STREAMID from StudentMaster 
        group by STREAMID))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STREAMID ORDER BY TOTALMARKS desc NULLS LAST) AS RANK,
               StudentMaster.name,
               stream.name AS stream,
               totalMarks AS HighestMarks
          FROM StudentMaster INNER JOIN STREAM USING (streamId))
 WHERE RANK = 1
```

It computes, for every row of the joined tables, the rank of the student in the stream, ordering by mark; the outer query simply filters to get only the students at the first places of every stream.
The ordering is done in descending order, and with NULL values in the latest position